# Pass params as function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

i am new on java-Script programming and i develope NodeJs.
I wanna call one Function, which requires functions as parameter:

Will be called:

```
module.exports = {
        //pool is has been defined
        connection: function() {
            pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {

                return conn;
            });
        }

};
```

At next other node.js file, which call that:

```
var connectionPool = require('./connPool.js');
var connection = connectionPool.connection;
var tempConnection  = connection.getConnection(???);
```

I need return-value from method "getConnection" (above this code)
How can i get it??

Thx.

Comment: Looks like `getConnection` is asynchronous.

Comment: and how can i fixed that? something mit callback, but i dont know exactly how...

Comment: See the duplicate question.